# aria-label and label not both read

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

Please consider the following markup.

```html
<label for="i1" class="inforLabel">This is a label</label>
<input id="i1" type="text" class="inforTextbox" aria-label="Title, not label" />
```

For me this markup is what is generated after my custom tooltip control. The issue I am seeing on JAWS on IE is that it only reads "Title, not label", however with other screen readers for example Voice over both the label and the textbox `aria-label` is read. I think it should read both.

Is this a setting or a bug? Or is there something else someone can recommend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For elements which have a descriptive label element already in the DOM, it is best to use the `aria-labelledby` attribute, instead of `aria-label`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-labelledby

From the documentation:

> The purpose of aria-labelledby is the same as that of aria-label. It provides the user with a recognizable name of the object.
>
> If the label text is visible on screen, authors SHOULD use aria-labelledby and SHOULD NOT use aria-label. Use aria-label only if the interface is such that it is not possible to have a visible label on the screen.

Individual screen reader and browser combinations can give inconsistent results when you don't follow the standard recommendations, as the WAI-ARIA spec can be open to interpretation.

Is is generally not a good idea to associate multiple labels with an accessible element. Labels should be concise. If you want to add extra description, you may also want to use `aria-describedby`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-describedby

In both cases, you will need to have an `id` on your label.

```
<label id="label1" for="input1" class="inforLabel">This is a label</label>
<input id="input1" type="text" class="inforTextbox" aria-labelledby="label1" />
```

Optionally, if you need to have multiple elements, you can try to put them in a div, with one element being offscreen.

```
<div id="accessible-label1">
  <label for="input1" class="inforLabel">This is a label</label>
  <span class="offscreen">Supplementary text</span>
</div>
<input id="input1" type="text" class="inforTextbox" aria-labelledby="accessible-label1" />
```

With appropriate CSS to position the offscreen class element off the screen, this should combine the text-content of the children of `accessible-label1` to use as the aria-label. Again, consider the use of `aria-describedby`.

Comment: Adding to this; the expected result from the original question is: `aria-label` should have precedence over `<label>`.  Based on the [WAI ARIA spec section Text Alternative Computation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-implementation/#mapping_additional_nd_te). In @Nick 's answer, `aria-labelledby` is the expected usage tho, which would have the highest precedence in the Text Alternative Computation scenarios

Comment: Having issues with an aria-label not being read by a screen reader. Any insight into how to get this functional.